# Aurelia bundle: error loading "aurelia-cli"

Tags: jspm, aurelia

When I run aurelia's bundler I get the following error:

```
D:\Code\Test>aurelia bundle
info: Using Aureliafile: D:\Code\Test\aureliafile.js
info: Creating bundle ...
Potentially unhandled rejection [6] Error: Error loading "aurelia-cli" at file:D:/Code/Test/aurelia-cli.js
Error loading "aurelia-cli" from "aureliafile" at file:D:/Code/Test/aureliafile.js
ENOENT, open 'D:\Code\Test\aurelia-cli.js'
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a combination of having set `"*" : "*.js"` in `System.Config` and using the `"*"` wildcard telling aurelia bundle to pull in everything. This turns out to try to include the project root files. You can either be more specific to the bundler:

**aureliafile.js:**

```
"dist/app-bundle": {
    modules: [
      'dist/*',
      ...
```

or reapply the jspm mapping `"*" : "dist/*.js"`. Unfortunatly what I need is actually one configuration during development (bundling) and another during production (serving).

related issues:

- https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/112
- https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/116